# Collapsing a Pivot Table Column within GoogleSheets via Macro / Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I'm trying to get around the Pivot Table Editor always displaying by using the protected sheet feature, but this disables the ability to expand and collapse my pivot table fields.

Can anyone help me with a really basic collapse and expand script / macro?

I've tried recording the action itself but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Hello @JonGoodwin! Could you please share the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are using so that we can better help you? And please remember to remove or anonymize any private information.

Comment: It's not really code, I'm trying to record the macro by clicking on the pivot table, but it doesn't seem to recognise me collapsing the field

    /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
    
    function CTCCostPlusCollapseProject() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('B13').activate();
    };

Comment: I have been researching your setup, but I can't fully replicate it. If you don't have any code, please share your actual Sheet and an example of your desired Sheet in order to reproduce your question.